# Calling method of jQuery from controller

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

I need a way to call a jQuery-UI method from a controller. The method is update method of sort-able. When view is ready I try to make it sort-able, but how to call the update method? The controller and view is like this:

```
App.theController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
 method:function(){
    //calling update method of sortable
 }
});

App.theView = Ember.View.extend({
didInsertElement:function(){
    this.$().sortable({
    update:function(){

    }
    });
  }
});
```

Now I want `method` call update method of `sortable` in view.

Comment: I never used the sortable plugin, but isn't the update argument a callback that gets called by the plugin? Why should you want to call it yourself?

Comment: i dont know how to call it by i ask another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076233/calling-a-method-of-view-in-emberjs) to find a way

Comment: What is the trigger for the update?
You probably want an observer in the view that will be dependant on that trigger on the controller.
Something like: update: function(){}.observes("controller.list")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `update` method of the sortable plugin to a function within the controller. So that, whenever `sortable()` update is called, the controller function is called:

```
App.theView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().sortable();
    var callback = this.get('controller.updateSortable');
    this.$().on('sortupdate', callback);
  }
});

App.theController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  updateSortable: function() {
    // call me when sortable() update is called
  }
});
```