# Calling a method of view in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a one method in my view and i want to call this method from controller.The controller and view is like this :

```
App.theController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
methodA:function(){
    //how to call methodB in view 
}
});
App.theView = Ember.View.extend({
methodB:function(){
    //do something
}
});
```

the question is how methodA can call methodB ?

Comment: This is not intended by Ember. You have to explain your usecase. There is a better way for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This method should probably be on the controller.

```
    App.TheController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        methodA:function(){
            //do something 
        }
    });

    App.TheView = Ember.View.extend({
        methodB:function(){
            this.get("controller").methodA();
        }
    });
```

You can reference both of them through the container's lookup method, but this is not a recommended practice.

Comment: Naming matters in this case, both controller and view must be named with the same prefix, right?

Comment: @Pavlo: Yes. Or you do the wiring of the controller and view yourself but this is more advanced stuff that you won't need in the beginning.